Как синхронизировать изменения в swagger и импортированной с него коллекции в postman?
Можно ли как то синхронизировать изменения, проводимые в swagger с postman. Например, в postman написаны тесты, скрипты, если в swagger что то изменилось, поменялась точка, добавились запросы. Нужно это перенести в Postman. Просто импортировать, он создать дубль коллекции.
Какие то поиски результатов особых не дали.
Как вариант, это что бы postman подсвечивал изменения, при замене json со сваггера в API postman.  -->
Есть swagger openapi 3.1
В APIs postmana создаю новый API, импортирую туда ссылку на swagger. Создается definition, далее из него вытаскиваем коллекцию.
После, если внести какие то изменения в json и обновить коллекцию, postman предложит обработать изменения и удалить старые запросы и добавить новые. Встает несколько моментов:

В ручную переносить все скрипты
Новые запросы будут вне папок, просто кинет их в низ списка коллекции
Если в ручную создать папку и запихать туда точки, ломается обновление коллекции

Возможно есть что то более изящное?
